# HTML, Body height 100% does not work

Tags: html, css, angularjs, cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok, so I have a mobile application with **Cordova** and **AngularJS**. For the styling I use **Less** and **Bootstrap**.

---

**Problem**

In the mobile app I have tried to size my divs with percentage (%). But this does not seem to work. I cannot seem to change the following behavior: `The divs are as big as the content inside of them`. This problem sounds quite easy and I have tried many options on here (stackoverflow) aswell as on the web. Yet I have not found the solution to fix it and it is getting quite annoying.

---

**I have tried**

Adding `html, body { height: 100% }`,

Adding `html, body, #canvas { height: 100%}`

Adding `#canvas { min-height: 100% }`

Adding `html { height: 100% } body { min-height: 100% }`

And a lot of other variations. Using **px** works, but I don't know how big my mobile device is, so that isn't realy handy.. (I also use bootstrap and some media queries for styling).

---

**Example**

When I add elements to my div I get the following behavior:

[image: HTML]

I want to remove that white empty space, but I can only achieve that when using **px** instead of **%**.

---

**Less example:**

```
html, body {
    background: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}

#canvas {
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;                 //prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;              //prevent webkit from resizing text to fit 
    -webkit-user-select: node;                   //prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text'  
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    background-color: @cgiColor;  
}

.header {
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    background: @companyColor;
    color: @textColor;
}

.incidentContainer {
    background: @appBodyColor;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    color: @textColor;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 15%;
    width: 100%;    
    background: @companyColor;
}
```

---

**Extra information**

I am using AngularJS, so my application is a single page application. My index.html looks as follows:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false" >  
   <div class="{{ pageClass}}"  ng-view ></div>        
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
   <script data-main="main" src="lib/require.js"></script>
</body>
```

With of course the standard links to my CSS sheets, and so on. 
All the other pages are includes in the '**ng-view**' and don't have any  or  tags. This because they are included.

---

**Solution**

The solution was to add the following CSS rule:

```
div[ng-view]{
     height: 100%;
}
```

This worked, because all divs (except for html & body) are children of this item. Adding the 100% made the div space span to 100% of the screen and thus provides a space for percentage to work.

***Credits go to Jai for this answer!***

Comment: We'll need to see the rendered HTML structure.

Comment: @steveax, added rendered HTML structure

Comment: @Mr.wiseguy Are you referring to the "Extra Information" section? It looks like Angular renders that post-pageload. Maybe you could open Developer Tools on the loaded page, right-click <body>, and then click Edit HTML, and copy it out of there? This is a styling issue, so we're only really concerned about how the HTML looks in the end. You can remove inner-level parts that you believe are not relevant (just write "Lots of Content" or something)

Comment: still can't see any rendered html, if your html is produced by the angular, then you need to inspect the element and paste the html from there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What seems to me, the directive `ng-view` is the parent of your application and `header, content, footer` are loaded in this div. So you have your `header` div at correct place, your footer is also placed correctly as it is absolutely positioned.

But in case of your content area, that is relative to the `ng-view` div.

I would recommend you to make it `100%` height. Something like:

```
div[ng-view]{
     height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: We probably need rendered HTML to confirm, but this sounds on-point. Specifically, make the `ng-view` 70% height as the employeeContainer is, then the employeeContainer 100% height (of the former element). Any other intermediate containers will need 100%.

Comment: Absolutely! The rendered markup will make thins much clear to answer. @Katana314

Comment: Can you give me a little more information about the 'div.pageclass'. Somehow the 'pageclass' translates to <div class ng-view> on runtime. So I do not know where I should add that piece of css. (Also, I have added rendered HTML code to my post)

Comment: @Mr.wiseguy check the update. You can target it with `ng-view` attribute.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you very much. This has been bothering me for a long time..

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to add the following css and set Important attribute

```
html, body { height: 100% !important }
```

Answer (score 3):

This most likely is because of the fact that in CSS the 100% is a relative value.

With width the default 100% is the width of the screen, or whatever you are looking at.

Height however does not take the height of the screen as 100%. It needs a solid value.

I think that if you change

```
html, body {
    background: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}
```

with

```
html, body {
    background: transparent;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}
```

it should work.

The 100vh should set the height of the html to the height of the viewport.

I guess this way works, I have to say though that I myself have not used something to get my page to have a height that is 100% of the screen.

Comment: I agree I think this approahc should work, but I disagree with the statement "*Height however does not take the height of the screen as 100%*" as I have done this myself for several pages.

Comment: It does not work, adding { height: 100vh } to my html, body tag results in the same view :(

Comment: @Katana314 In my experience it did not work, but if my statement is not true in your experience then I guess my experience is lacking  
Mr.wiseguy I am sad to say that I do not know of a other solution

Answer (score 0):

Yay, rendered HTML!

**`class="incident"` is only expanded as large as it needs to be**. I believe your fix should be to make *that* element have a height of 70% (because it will be relative to the whole-page) and then incidentContainer should have a height of 100%.

Percentage heights are relative to the parent element, not the root, so you need to be very aware of any containers, even ones stealthily added by a framework.

Also, if it helps, Jelmergu suggested the `vh` unit type. This could fit your use case - one "Viewport Height" is equivalent to "1% of the browser's content area". So, 100vh would take up the whole screen. This is true even on deep-level children.